# smartdiagram "uniform color list" option causes spacing bug

Tags: spacing, smartdiagram

I think I found a bug in the [smartdiagram](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram) package. The "uniform color list" option lets you specify one color for `<n>` items. However, when specifying a number `<n>`, a horizontal space is inserted on the left side of the generated flow diagram. The higher the specified number `<n>` is, the larger the space gets.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

  \smartdiagramset{
    % remove this option or increase the value for <n> to compare the spacing
    uniform color list=gray!40 for 5 items
  }

  \smartdiagram[flow diagram]{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five}

\end{document}
```

When removing the "uniform color list" option, the space on the left disappears. The issue gets really obvious when increasing the number `<n>` to a value of  100 for example.

Here is a comparision of the two generated documents, where in the first the "uniform color list" option is specified with an `<n>` of 5 and in the second it is not specified.

[image: smartdiagram comparision]

My current workaround is that I don't use the "uniform color list" option at all. Instead, I redefine all predefined colors and set them to the same desired value like this:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{color@1}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@2}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@3}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@4}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@5}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@6}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@7}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@8}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@9}{gray!40}
\@namedef{color@10}{gray!40}
\makeatother
```

This is not an ideal solution. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I sent mail to the package author about the bug.

Comment: Great, thank you! I just thought about doing the same.

Comment: I have fixed the bug in the version 0.3b of the package already available on CTAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

> This behaviour is due to a bug in `smartdiagram` which is fixed
>   in the `2016/12/23 v0.3b` release. Where possible, you should [update your TeX
>   distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
>   current release. If this is not possible, for example if you want to
>   change only this one package or where you do not have the privileges
>   to update the entire distribution, you will need to [install the
>   package locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since for more complex packages there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.

## Original answer (based on version 0.3a `smartdiagram`)

Unprotected end-of-lines:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/smart diagram/.cd, uniform color list/.code args={#1 for #2 items}{%
      \foreach \listitem [count=\i] in {1,...,#2}{%
         \global\@namedef{color@\i\expandafter}\expandafter{#1}%
      }%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \smartdiagramset{
    % remove this option or increase the value for <n> to compare the spacing
    uniform color list=gray!40 for 5 items
  }

  \smartdiagram[flow diagram]{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The original code in `smartdiagramlibrarycore.definitions.code.tex`

```
168 \pgfkeys{/smart diagram/.cd, uniform color list/.code args={#1 for #2 items}{
169       \foreach \listitem [count=\i] in {1,...,#2}{
170          \global\@namedef{color@\i\expandafter}\expandafter{#1}
171       }
172    }
173 }
```

Also the code for `use predefined color list` should be fixed:

```
\pgfkeys{/smart diagram/.cd, use predefined color list/.code={%
      \@namedef{color@1}{red!30}%
      \@namedef{color@2}{cyan!30}%
      \@namedef{color@3}{blue!30}%
      \@namedef{color@4}{green!30}%
      \@namedef{color@5}{orange!30}%
      \@namedef{color@6}{yellow!30}%
      \@namedef{color@7}{magenta!30}%
      \@namedef{color@8}{brown!30}%
      \@namedef{color@9}{violet!30}%
      \@namedef{color@10}{teal!30}%
   }%
}
```

In general, all `.code` parts should get similar protections.